# Pegar preços de produtos em uma array, somá-los e apresentar o total da soma em um TextView

Tags: java, android, firebase

Olá, pessoal, então, estou tendo uma dificuldade para resolver um problema aqui, estou usando um MultiAutoCompleteTextView para pegar produtos e seus preços no banco de dados Firebase do app,já consigo apresentar todos os produtos dentro do autocomplete, porém, eu gostaria de pegar o preço de cada produto, somar todos e apresentar o total em uma TextView, porém não tenho noção de por onde começar. Não sei se devo pegar cada elemento da ArrayList e somar, ou se devo fazer de outra forma. Caso possam me ajudar, ficarei bem grato.

```
  firebase.child("Produtos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Is better to use a List, because you don't know the size
            // of the iterator returned by dataSnapshot.getChildren() to
            // initialize the array
            final List<String> produto1 = new ArrayList<>();

            for (final DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                produto = areaSnapshot.child("nome").getValue(String.class);
                valor = areaSnapshot.child("valor").getValue(String.class);
                produto1.add("Serviço: " + produto + " - Valor: R$" + valor);
                totalParaPagar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
                int [] an = new int[0];
            }


            produtoRamissao = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(OrdemServicoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, produto1);
            areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
            produtoRamissao.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
            produtoRamissao.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: Crie um variável global e faça a soma dentro do `for`. `soma += Integer.parseInt(valor);`. Depois utilize o método `setText` para exibir no `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Mano  você está usando um ArrayList de Strings (List), e concatenando valores, então não vai conseguir resgatar os valores saparados.
Então a primeira coisa a ser feita é criar uma classe de objetos com  os elementos que deseja inserir na list, por exemplo:

```
public class Produtos{

    private String nome;
    private String valor;

    public String getNome() { return nome; }

    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

    public String getValor() { return valor; }

    public void setValor(String valor) { this.valor = valor; }
}
```

Agora ao invés de criar a `List<String>`, vai criar um `List<Produtos>`, e implementar da seguinte forma:

```
List<Produtos> produto1 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            produto = areaSnapshot.child("nome").getValue(String.class);
            valor = areaSnapshot.child("valor").getValue(String.class);

            Produtos itemProduto = new Produtos();
            itemProduto.setNome(produto);
            itemProduto.setValor(valor);
            produto1.add(itemProduto);

            totalParaPagar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
            int [] an = new int[0];
        }
```

Desta forma você pode resgatar os valores onde desejar com os gets, ex:

```
produto1.get(posicao).getNome();
produto1.get(posicao).getValor();
```

Pode usá-los onde quiser,concatenar pra exibir na textview, ou até transformar em double pra fazer cálculos, ex:

```
double total = Double.parseDouble(produto1.get(0).getValor()) * Double.parseDouble(produto1.get(1).getValor())
```

Comment: @Brian, aceite esta resposta se ela te ajudou, para que os outros saibam que o seu problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Brenddon, então, ajudou até certo ponto, porque não consegui atingir o êxito. Me ajudou a aprender mais sobre, mas não resolvi o problema.